# Javascript objects: how are these two values different?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm pretty new to OOP, and I'm having trouble discerning why I am getting different values for the two console logs. The first log gives me the correct height value, the second one which accesses the value through an object property is telling me the height is 0. I can also say that if I run a console log on `imageLoader.images[this.sprite]`, and on `player1.height` when `this.height = imageLoader.images[this.sprite]` (so basically I removed the .height property from each value), the first log correctly names the sprite even when it has been dynamically changed, while the second log once again is incorrect and only names the sprite that the object was assigned on creation (from the imageName argument).

As a little bit of background, the constructor is pulling images from the object *images* from within the object *imageLoader*, with each actual image contained in a property named after the image's name. I want to have access to each image's height through the height property of each new Thing.

```
function Thing(imageName) {
    this.sprite = imageName;
    this.height = imageLoader.images[this.sprite].height;
}

var player1 = new Thing ("face_right");

console.log(imageLoader.images[player1.sprite].height);
console.log(player1.height);
```

Hope that was somewhat clear. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Right, there must be something between the instanciation and logs. Please describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show any code that would cause the sprite to change, but you seem to be saying you want the `player1.height` to automatically update to reflect the height of whatever the current sprite is, where the sprite can change dynamically? If so it won't work the way you currently have it because the `this.height` property you set will just be a primitive number value - it's not a reference to the other object's property. You'd need to add code to change the `Thing` instance's `.height` property when the sprite is updated.

Or instead of having a `.height` property have a `.height()` method - or perhaps call it `.getHeight()` as follows:

```
function Thing(imageName) {
    this.sprite = imageName;
    this.getHeight = function() {
        return imageLoader.images[this.sprite].height;
    }
}

var player1 = new Thing ("face_right");
console.log(player1.getHeight());
```